# Scenekit / Spritekit remove node causing crash

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, crash, scenekit, skaction

What I'm try to do, is replicate some digital instrument gauge ...using Spritekit..

[image: instrument]

On my project I have to use a SpriteKit Scene as material for Scenekit SCNnode.

In order to do that I create a sub class of SKscene and and apply it as "material.diffuse.contents" of the SCNNode.

all working fine, I can see my SKscene as material of the SCNNode.

Here the issue:

I try to animate/replicate the correct indication of the instrument based of some value my app received from other source.

To do so, i decide to use the SKsceneDelegate and use the method "update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)"

simply the update method look for the sknode of the green needle "fulcro" remove it , and make a new line calculating the angle and new coordinate for the new line.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        
        guard let fulcroToRemove = self.childNode(withName: "fulcro") else {return}
        fulcroToRemove.removeFromParent() // issue here... 

        let fulcro = SKNode()
        fulcro.name = "fulcro"
        fulcro.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 260)
        let line = makeLine(startPos: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                            endPos: getCoordinate(angleDeg: getCurrentEGT()),
                            name: "EGT_LINE")
        fulcro.addChild(line)
        self.addChild(fulcro)
    }
```

... if I try this SKscene itself in a project only with Spritekit all working fine.. I can see my needle increase the value correctly when the data source increase.

But if use the same SKscene as material of SceneKit getting the following error:

[image: error]

look like I'm removing something not correctly .. and I can see fulcroToRemove.removeFromParent() is the line trigger the error.

But why ??How I can remove the line to avoid the crash?

Comment: It's just a thought, but maybe you'd better use the SceneKit "updateAtTime" function for SceneKit objects and SpriteKit's "update currentTime" for SpriteKit objects. (?)

Comment: Hello, that what I’m doing.. and I can’t understand why it trigger the error on SceneKit…  but the render I’m using is of sprite kit. I didt even write ✍️ the code updateAtTime I use only update currentTime on my subclass SKScene

Comment: Does the Error occur immediatly (the first time the Update Function runs?) or like after some duration (10 sec... one minuete)? Are you using Real Device or the Simulator?

Comment: it appear right immediately I soon I run the app on the simulator.. good Idea I should try it on the real device.. I did't...